# Accessing to Laravel server from android phone at a port

Tags: php, android, linux, laravel-5, server

Trying to access to Laravel server at localhost:8000 from android phone.
What I did:

- Laptop & android phone is connected to same router.
- started Laravel server at localhost at port 8000
- laptop's ip for the router i.e. 192.168.0.110
- from phone browser tried to visit 192.168.0.110:8000

If I visit 192.168.0.110 then the default page from php server loads. But when trying to connect to that port (8000 for this example) - shows error page saying:

> This site can't be reached

In laptop's browser I can visit localhost:8000

What's wrong am I doing?

What to do to connect?

**For more** OS:: Linux Mint and firewall (ufw) is turned off.

**Update**
Couldn't solve the issue. Using ngrok instead. ngrok creates a publicly shareable url tunnelled to your localhost:port.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: Tried that solution in the first place but failed.

Comment: *Please remember to turn off the firewall in computer aswell.*

Comment: Firewall is turned off

Answer (score 9):

Type this in laravel application `command` line

**`php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0`**

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same challenge when i was developing a barcode verification app. This was my solution:

I ran the following code so as to be able to use my system IP to access the laravel server

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

After running the code, I was able to access my laravel server from both my browser and android app through links like:

```
http://192.168.0.160/barcode/public/checker
```

or

```
http://192.168.0.160:8000/checker/
```

Also don't forget to include this in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of
 localhost:8080 use
 **10.0.0.2:8000**
 this url.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to serve to the application; please follow the following procedures

1. Connect your phone and your computer on the same network, if you sing a wifi network, or a router or even if you serve your computer with your mobile wifi run this command

for linux

> `ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1`

Result Example

> inet 192.168.250.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
> inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
> inet 192.168.43.210  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255

for windows

> `ipconfig`
> Result Use the IP4 Adress is the ip of your computer

2. Then take the ip address of your computer the serve your project with a ip by specify the host

> `php artisan serve --host=<Your Computer Ip Address>`

3. now you can take your phone an open the phone browser then access the application using the ip of the computer and the port number that was used when you run `php artisan serve` Example `http://192.168.43.210:8000`

> if you don't want to specify the port number when visit the application on your phone use the following command `php artisan serve --host=<Your Computer Ip> --port=80` Then when visit the application on your phone use only the ip address of your computer without the port number Example `http://192.168.43.210` **NOTE:** On linux system you may have to use sudo in order to use this command `sudo php artisan serve --host=192.168.43.210 --port=80`

Reference Link
[Laracast How to access laravel website in phone](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-to-access-laravel-website-in-phone)